# how to get source of an javascript from its function name

Tags: javascript, console

Sometimes it occurs that I like a feature on an page and want to read its javascript,
but it is an difficult task to manually find where the function is especially when the webpages more than one js files.

Is there a way I can get/copy the only required js file by its name which I can easily get by inspecting page.
examole:

```
<div id='abc()'></div>
```

Now how to fine the source of function `div()`?

Comment: Am I the only one who found that function `abc` was called from the `id` attribute of `<div>` tag?

Comment: In fact it's not a function call at all, just a strange id...

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution for a function which is defined in the global scope :

1. open the console of your browser (`F12` in most browsers)
2. type the name of the function

For example type `klass` in the console on this page.

In the general case, you really need to [learn to use the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console), including [the debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

---

Regarding your practical question : what changes the background of the http://www.noisli.com/ page :

- it's not the `changebackground` function : this function doesn't exist
- it's in the first line of jplayer.js

But the way I found it is too hacky, I hacked the `Math.random` function by typing this in the console :

```
Math.random = function(){ debugger; return Math.random() }
```

so that I would enter in debug and see the call stack...

I hope somebody can propose a clean way.

Comment: I'd better formulate as *Learn how to use a debugger*.

Comment: @VisioN: Then perhaps you could help in teaching this valuable skill, instead of just being a dick. What are you here for, again?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That was rude.

Comment: @VisioN Both comments are a little excessive, as often happens in internet interaction :) <-- here's a smiley to be sure I hurt nobody

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was not attempting to help the OP in this question. My comment was to the dystroy's answer that to my mind can be rewritten shortly as *Learn how to use a debugger*. Am I wrong? What are you nervous for? You haven't tried to help the OP either, should I also call you a dick and continue saying roughnesses?

Comment: I was trying to find an function source "changebackground()" on website http://www.noisli.com/ but it returns an error

Comment: @baibavkumar Well, the function doesn't exist, maybe because there's an error before it get defined, or maybe because it was removed.

Comment: I was trying to get the code of how background color changes with time can you please help me out of it..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Excuse me but "you seemed to be suggesting ..." plus all mentioned doesn't entitle you to offend me. I am not a little boy, I know what I say, where and when. I know the limits you are talking about and never attempt to outrage anyone. If you feel yourself inconsistent with someone's opinion, examine the situation first before flaming.

Comment: The holidays bring out the best in people...

Comment: Merry christmas, @rlemon! This is pretty much the best in me ;)

Comment: @VisioN: That is my exact advice to you, with regards to how you approach contributing to a question on Stack Overflow. Happy holidays.

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute boormakrlets in your address-bar, you could do:

```
javascript:abc.toString()
```

Or better:

```
javascript:alert(abc.toString())
```

Comment: UM, why would you do that in the address bar and not in the console? It is not 1999 anymore. :)

Comment: You're right, bum I'm too lazy to open the console :p

Comment: @Nippey that's shameful.

Comment: Shame on me :) But HEY it's backwards compatible. Maybe I'm still surfing with IE5.. ^^

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach. Not every debugging technique requires a huge "console" or developer tools plug-in.

Comment: I was trying to find an function source "changebackground()" on website http://www.noisli.com/ but it returns an error